# How to Scale an image axis in windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone, scaletransform

I am using 4 images in grid as shown.Now I want to scaled the corresponding image on tap to size  of the grid in the mention  arrow direction for e.g

image2 size(width and height) = grid(dimension) on tap and image2 scaled to its left as mention in diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this

[Resizing Images in Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/09/resizing-images-in-windows-phone-7.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I need storyboard so that if image scale it will be visible and the scaling of image is done as shown in the above image in the arrow direction on tap on respective image.